# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot mount /boot/efi

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, efi

I have an Ubuntu Server installation that doesn't start up because the disk which contained the EFI partition is broken. I inserted a new HDD and created a new EFI partition by using GParted (new GPT table, create FAT32) and then I ran `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdeX1` on it.

To reinstall the EFI partitions content (GRUB and boot entry), I followed the accepted answer on this Ask Ubuntu question ([How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?](https://askubuntu.com/a/831241)).

While reinstalling GRUB, the following warnings occurred:
[image: Reinstall Picture]

After a restart, the system boots, but cannot mount the EFI partition. I set the entry in fstab to the same ID that was given by `blkid /dev/sdX1`.  Here are some images: (note that the EFI partition is on `/dev/sde1` now)

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

How can I make the system start up correctly, by mounting the EFI partition?

Comment: What does your `/etc/fstab` look like?

Comment: Mount the EFI partition in `/boot/efi`. The command would be like this: `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB`.